# How to map a pixel number of an image into another resolution image

Tags: image, image-processing, pixel

I have a pixel number of an image of resolution (720X576). Now I would like to locate that pixel in the same image of different resolution (1920X1080).

How can I able to map the pixel number to get same pixel location in other image also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should get the coordinates from received pixel number. For suppose p1 is the given pixel number of image(720X576), then its corresponding coordinates are

```
y = p1/720;
x = p1 - y*720;
```

Then, convert these x & y into other resolution(1920X1080) x, y as follows

```
x1 = x*1920.0/720;
y1 = y*1080.0/576;
```

At last convert these x1 & y1 into pixel location in 1920X1080 as follows,

p2 = x1+y1*1920;

p2 is the needed pixel location.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the x coordinate by 1920/720 and the y coordinate by 1080/576, but it may not be that simple because of resampling and compression artefacts.